# Using Timer in a MVC Application to do a task every 5 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to set up a function using a Timer (or some similar approach) that would allow a C# MVC application to do a certain task (in my case, I want to go through database and update specific records every 5 minutes). I have the code I want to be executed, but I don't know how to set it up to be executed every 5 minutes regardless of whether someone is using the application or not (basically I want the task to start running as soon as application is deployed and to never stop (not really never, but when application is erased from server)).

I'm currently using Shared Windows Hosting, so can't access Task Scheduler.

Comment: short answer: you can't and you shouldn't. your app pool might get killed by IIS anytime and there is no guarantee that your task will run to the end or if it will ever resume after getting killed

Comment: use windows Task Scheduler or Windows Service instead

Comment: @Steve updated reason why I can't user Task Scheduler. Is Windows Service accessible on Shared Hosting?

Comment: Use a Azure webjob, setting a cron expression for every 5 minutes

Comment: @KrumBagashev Why do you assume the OP has access to or wants to use Azure?

Comment: @KrumBagashev Seems like an option, but I if possible, I'd avoid Azure and stay on my Shared Hosting account, but if not possible, Azure seems just fine

Comment: @AlenŠimunic in such case you need to have detection logic to restart the task. Something has to constantly pinging the url to keep your app pool alive. your task has to be able to be able to live thru force kill (not screw things up). Otherwise just spend more $$ and get a VPS. The $ you saved from hacking up a solution for shared host is not worth the time IMO

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You can always add Authentication or whitelist with a firewall rule only to be visible to the Internal Infrastructure

Comment: @Steve Thank you, I now fully understand that an additional service should be taken (Azure timer functions seems like a feasible solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web applications hosted within IIS or other web servers are generally not designed to run timed or long running tasks - your task could be killed anytime by the web server. Offload this work to Windows Task Scheduler, a Windows Service, or timed Azure Function/AWS Lambda (if in cloud)

Comment: This fully answers my question, thank you